# Native base Select component open my keyboard

Tags: react-native, native-base

I am using native-base Select component and when I try to open Select items it opens keyboard instead. On ios works perfect, i can hide dropdownicon and click anywhere on Select field and it will open Select items, but on android i can open only when i press on dropdownicon.
I'm using native-base 3.4.28, previously use 3.2.1 and it works on both ios and android, after the upgrade it doesnt.

```
<Select
          flex={1}
          // @ts-ignore
          dropdownIcon={() => null}
          selectedValue={props.value}
          placeholder="Gender"
          _selectedItem={{
            bg: 'primary.100',
            endIcon: <CheckIcon size="5" />,
          }}
          onValueChange={props.handleChange}
          fontWeight={props.value ? 600 : 400}
          fontSize={'14px'}
          {...props.selectProps}
        >
          <Select.Item label="Female" value={Gender.FEMALE} />
          <Select.Item label="Male" value={Gender.MALE} />
          <Select.Item label="Non binary" value={Gender.NON_BINARY} />
          <Select.Item
            label="Not listed above"
            value={Gender.NOT_LISTED_ABOVE}
          />
          <Select.Item
            label="Prefer not to say"
            value={Gender.PREFER_NOT_TO_SAY}
          />
        </Select>
```

I tried to dismiss the Keyboard within onOpen prop but isn't working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To anyone who is facing the same issue and don't want to modify that much, just add the `isReadOnly` flag to the `<FormControl />` :

````
<FormControl isReadOnly>
        <FormControl.Label>{label}</FormControl.Label>
        <Controller...
    ```
````

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem and found this fix on the native-base github: https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/5723

It happens when the select is placed inside a FormControl, outside it works fine.

You can wrap the label and the error separately like this and the select will work fine:

```
<FormControl isInvalid={hasError}>
                <FormControl.Label>{label}</FormControl.Label>
              </FormControl>
              <Select
                minWidth="200"
                selectedValue={value}
                onValueChange={itemValue => onChange(itemValue)}
                _selectedItem={{
                  //bg: 'teal.600',
                  endIcon: <CheckIcon size={5} />,
                }}
                mt="1">
                {renderSelectItems()}
              </Select>
              {hasError && (
                <FormControl isInvalid={hasError}>
                  <FormControl.ErrorMessage
                    leftIcon={<WarningOutlineIcon size="xs" />}>
                    {errorMessage}
                  </FormControl.ErrorMessage>
                </FormControl>
              )}
```